# Rally Excel Add-in Closed projects?

Tags: excel, rally

I would like to use the Excel Add in to connect to Rally.  The query would be to look for a user story and tell me the project along with the other standard information.

My problem is that the user story is in a closed project.  I know this by the "(0 of 1)" hint when I look at a the successor information of another story and then it's revision history.

I currently receive no results.  It appears that this add-in will only look at open projects.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to retrieve information from closed projects is to re-open them temporarily, obtain the needed reporting, and then close them. WS API queries are scoped to open projects only for performance reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This is what I thought was the situation.  Is there any other method, besides the excel add-in,  I can use to query closed projects?